# Definition of an electron volt

Tags: electrostatics, energy, charge, conventions, si-units

One electron volt is defined as the kinetic energy of a electron in a potential of $1$ volt.

Hence, by conservation of energy, electric potential energy = kinetic energy:

$$ q V = \mathrm{K.E.} $$

As the charge of an electron is $-e$ and the voltage is $1\mathrm{V}$, the kinetic energy would be $-e$ joules, which will be $-1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ joules.

But Google says $1\mathrm{eV} = +1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ joules

How is that possible?

This is the definition of $1$ electron volt which I know. Am I right?

Comment: The potential of the electron *decreases* by 1V

Comment: kinetic energy can't be negative.

Comment: What makes you believe that "electric potential energy = kinetic energy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence, by conservation of energy,
>
> electric potential energy = kinetic energy
>
> q x V = K.E

This is not a correct expression for the conservation of energy. The conservation of energy would be $$E_{total}=E_{potential}+E_{kinetic}=const.$$ So, if we start with the electron at rest at 0 V then we get the total energy is 0 J and therefore $$E_{kinetic}=-E_{potential}$$ which resolves your concern